# How to forward request from servlet doGet method to new html/jsp page

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating chart js(bar chart) using java servlet and html i have a form which has two date fields and a submit button which on click forward my action to servlet where i am returning data
in form of json and in my new html there is javascript which has ajax call, which is calling MYServlet method but when iam passing dates from user the date value takes null and dosent display any thing in html pagei want to display them on a html page
Below is my html Form

```
    Below is my html Form
         <form id="form Id" action="MyServlet"
                    method="get">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h4>Start Date:</h4>
                        <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276"
                            placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
                        <h4>End Date:</h4>
                        <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276"
                            placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
                        <div>
                            <br>
                            <button id="test" style="border-radius: 4px;" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </form>


**below is my servlet whic is getting data from db an converting it to hson object to display chart in new html**

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            String fromdate=request.getParameter("fromdate");
            String todate=request.getParameter("todate");

            String str = null;
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Map<Object, Object> map = null;
            List<Map<Object, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>>();
            int xVal ,yVal,zVal,aVal,bVal;

            try {
                con = DBConnection.createConnection();
                statement = con.createStatement();
    String sql="select  sum(a.CASH) Cashamount,sum(a.CREDITCARD) Creditcardamount,sum(a.COUPONS) Couponamount,sum(a.CHEQUE) PAYTMamount,sum(a.CREDIT) Creditamount  from syncbill a  where  a.CANCELLED<>'Y' and a.billdate between '"+fromdate+"' and '"+todate+"'";
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
                    xVal = resultSet.getInt("Cashamount");
                    map.put("CashamountX", "Cashamount");
                    map.put("CashamountY", xVal);

                    yVal = resultSet.getInt("Creditcardamount");
                    map.put("CreditcardamountX", "Creditcardamount");
                    map.put("CreditcardamountY", yVal);

                    zVal = resultSet.getInt("Couponamount");
                    map.put("CouponamountX", "Couponamount");
                    map.put("CouponamountY", zVal);

                    aVal = resultSet.getInt("PAYTMamount");
                    map.put("PAYTMamountX", "PAYTMamount");
                    map.put("PAYTMamountY", aVal);

                    bVal = resultSet.getInt("Creditamount");
                    map.put("CreditamountX", "Creditamount");
                    map.put("CreditamountY", bVal);

                    list.add(map);
                    str = gson.toJson(list);

                }

                response.setContentType("application/json");

                response.getWriter().write(str);

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

**and finally my chart js html file having chart and java script**

```
<div id="chart-container">
        <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

<script>
        $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "MyServlet",
                        method : "GET",
                        success : function(data) {
                            var player = [];
                            var score = [];

                            for ( var i in data) {
                                player.push(data[i].CashamountX);
                                score.push(data[i].CashamountY);

                                player.push(data[i].CreditcardamountX);
                                score.push(data[i].CreditcardamountY);

                                player.push(data[i].CouponamountX);
                                score.push(data[i].CouponamountY);

                                player.push(data[i].PAYTMamountX);
                                score.push(data[i].PAYTMamountY);

                                player.push(data[i].CreditamountX);
                                score.push(data[i].CreditamountY);
                            }
                            var chartdata = {
                                labels : player,
                                datasets : [ {
                                    label : 'Amount',
                                    backgroundColor : [ '#6495ED', '#FFF8DC',
                                            '#008B8B', '#DCDCDC', '#E6E6FA' ],
                                    borderColor : 'black',
                                    hoverBackgroundColor : '#B0C4DE',
                                    hoverBorderColor : 'red',
                                    data : score
                                } ]
                            };

                            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

                            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                                type : 'bar',
                                data : chartdata
                            });
                        },
                        error : function(data) {

                        }
                    });
                });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the Ajax function on the submit event of the form. like following,

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#form_id").submit(function(event){ // don't put space in id or name in HTML
        event.preventDefault(); // to stop form being submitted because it reloads the page.
        $.ajax({
            url : "MyServlet",
            method : "GET",
            data : {
                fromdate : $("#startdate").val(),
                todate : $("#enddate").val()
            }, 
            success : function(data) {
                // your success function
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here your form, your canvas and your script should have to be in the same file. and also you can omit the `action="MyServlet"` attribute from the form.

**EDIT :**  here is the full code of your program

```html
<html>
<body>
<form id="form_id" method="get">
    <div class="container">
        <h4>Start Date:</h4>
        <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
        <h4>End Date:</h4>
        <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />
        <div>
            <br>
            <button id="test" style="border-radius: 4px;" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="chart-container">
    <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#form_id").submit(function(event){ // don't put space in id or name in HTML
            event.preventDefault(); // to stop form being submitted because it reloads the page.
        $.ajax({
            url : "MyServlet",
            method : "GET",
            data : {
                fromdate : $("#startdate").val(), // my bad it's val not value.
                todate : $("#enddate").val()
            }, 
            success : function(data) {
                $("#form_id").hide(); // this will hide the form.
                var player = [];
                var score = [];
                for ( var i in data) {
                    player.push(data[i].CashamountX);
                    score.push(data[i].CashamountY);
                    
                    player.push(data[i].CreditcardamountX);
                    score.push(data[i].CreditcardamountY);
                    
                    player.push(data[i].CouponamountX);
                    score.push(data[i].CouponamountY);

                    player.push(data[i].PAYTMamountX);
                    score.push(data[i].PAYTMamountY);

                    player.push(data[i].CreditamountX);
                    score.push(data[i].CreditamountY);
                }
                var chartdata = {
                    labels : player,
                    datasets : [ {
                        label : 'Amount',
                        backgroundColor : [ '#6495ED', '#FFF8DC',
                            '#008B8B', '#DCDCDC', '#E6E6FA' ],
                        borderColor : 'black',
                        hoverBackgroundColor : '#B0C4DE',
                        hoverBorderColor : 'red',
                        data : score
                    }]
                };

                var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

                var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type : 'bar',
                    data : chartdata
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean to say that i should write my form,canvas,and javascript in a single html file?

Comment: I am taking date Fields from users.

Comment: Yes, If you are using ajax to get the data from the servlet. You can hide the form once the data from the servlet is fetched and display the chart which gives the illusion of the new page.

Comment: how form get hide?  if i execute the code u have written above will it hide the form on submit event?

Comment: you can add $("#form_id").hide() in your success  function in ajax call to hide the form.

Comment: Bro can you please give me the full code because its not working here, actually i have very basic knowledge in ajax thats you. If you can please share the code with hide and how to show canvas on the same page.

Comment: I am giving from date and to date from user but it is not taking that it shows on console null.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

HashMap>> list = new HashMap<>();
        list.put("data", allData);

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Comment: on giving action to MyServlet it only goes to MyServlet and shows the data in JSON format it dosent goes to  the html file which has canvas.